# Change Font For NSButton With Inspectable/Designable Property

Tags: swift, xcode, fonts, nsbutton

Not sure how to do this. I found a chunk of code for a custom NSButton class that makes inspectable properties for font size and color but that's it. Is there a way to add the font sets on my Mac into a property that I can change for this class, or maybe get the font I've set in the other settable attributes, like the title? Here is the class:

```swift
import Cocoa

class TextButton: NSButton {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }

    @IBInspectable open var textColor: NSColor = NSColor.black
    @IBInspectable open var textSize: CGFloat = 10


    public override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let titleParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        titleParagraphStyle.alignment = alignment

        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [.foregroundColor: textColor, .font: NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: textSize), .paragraphStyle: titleParagraphStyle]
        self.attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.title, attributes: attributes)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Seems to work. I'm looking for a way to make an unbeveled push button for proper highlighting when clicked but IB won't let you do that. A round button is a style you can select but it's discouraged so I have to look further for a solution to that.

```
@IBDesignable
class TextButton: NSButton
{
    @IBInspectable var textColor: NSColor?

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        if let textColor = textColor, let font = font
        {
            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.alignment = .center

            let attributes =
                [
                    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
                    NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
                    NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: style
                    ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

            let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
            self.attributedTitle = attributedTitle
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)
    {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```